# stuck on color change in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am just a newbie in OpenCV. I was testing a program to convert all green pixels of an image to white.

Input:

[image: I have chosen this sample image:]

and this is my python program to do it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('exp.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
row,cols,layer=img.shape


for i in range (row):
    for j in range (cols):
     a=img[i,j]
     if(a[1]>128):
      img[i, j] = [255, 255, 255]
cv2.imshow('a',img)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The program works pretty fine but some part of the desired picture is lost too.

[image: This is the output image]

I dont know what went wrong.I even checked the BGR value at that pixel by

```
print(img[432,144])
```

and it's output was [ 37 209  37].I don't think its the actual color there as when I use them in rgbtohex.net to view that color, it was nothing like it.
I don't know where it went wrong with that. Pardon me if I am wrong about anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rethink your `if` statment for it to work better with those images, and not include unwanted pixels. For exemaple [0 255 255] is Cyan but it will also will get included cus `if(a[1]>128):`  so `a[1] = 255` and `if 255 > 128`.

Now we know that we want `G` to be high valued and `R` or `B` low valued, example solution would be `if(a[1] > 200 and a[0] < 128 and a[2] < 128)`.

Of course my example may work even worse then your on a diffrent image, that why  you want to  use some image processing tools first.You may learn more about it here [image procesing](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html)